# Get file name from Xdocument after Linq query

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I'm querying a bunch of SGML documents for specific Element and Attributes. This works ok and will display a message box when it finds the file which contains the specified items. However, what i need it to do is also give me the name of the file it's found them in, otherwise it's next to useless. I can't seem to find a way to get the filename of the file. I have:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(sgmlReader);
IEnumerable<XElement> selectedElement =
    from el in doc.Descendants(Element_textBox.Text)
        where (string)el.Attribute(Attribute_textBox.Text) == Value_textBox.Text
        select el; 
        //need to select the DMC and title and put in a variable, and list them


foreach (XElement elem in selectedElement)
   //Console.WriteLine(elem);

   MessageBox.Show("Data Module Found: " + elem);
```

As I say, I need to somehow identify the file from which the query finds a match. Any ideas?

Comment: What type has sgmlReader? Why you can't use name of file which was  loaded to XDocument?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify that the document's base URI must be set on load:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(@"file.xml", LoadOptions.SetBaseUri);
```

Then you can get the document URI from any element:

```
var someElement = doc.Root;
var uri = element.Document.BaseUri;
Console.WriteLine(uri);    // Prints: file:///C:/file.xml
```

---

If you are using a `Stream` or `TextReader`, you have to get the filename from somewhere else and store it yourself. Otherwise there is no way to get the filename.

Imagine I passed a `MemoryStream` or `NetworkStream` to `XDocument.Load()`, then there is no filename. In general, when working with streams or readers, you don't have a file name.

However there is one exception: if you can get the base stream of the reader and cast it to a `FileStream`, then you can get the filename:

```
var fs = File.OpenRead(@"C:\myxml.xml");
var reader = new StreamReader(fs);
DoSomething(reader);

static void DoSomething(TextReader reader)
{
    var streamReader = reader as StreamReader;
    if (streamReader != null)
    {
        var fileStream = streamReader.BaseStream as FileStream;
        if (fileStream != null)
            Console.WriteLine(fileStream.Name);
        else { /* No filename */ }
    }
    else { /* No filename */ }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Looks like BaseUri not working with stream being passed to document (as in question)